# WSO2 ESB Proxy for a BE service deployed on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, wso2, tomcat7, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have a SOAP web service deployed on Tomcat which needs https to be consumed. Now I need a proxy with WSO2 ESB to implement a PEP for a XACML authorization policy using WSO2 IS as a PDP. Now i'm having a lot of troubles with the various public keys. Which certificates do I need to import and where?

Tomcat: do I need WSO2 ESB certificate to do this?
WSO2 ESB: I think I need both WSO2 IS and Tomcat certificates? Am I right?
WSO2 IS: I think only the WSO2 ESB certificate is needed.

Am I right? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling HTTPS services from WSO2 ESB.

1. Entitlement web service of WSO2 IS
2. SOAP service in Tomcat

Here WSO2 ESB acts as an client in SSL handshake and WSO2 IS and Tomcat are acting as servers. In SSL handshake, client need to trust the server. Therefore client must have the certificate of the server.

Actually,

1. If server have a CA signed certificate, client must have the CA certificate chain in its trust store.
2. If server have a self signed certificate, client must have the server's certificate in its trust store

Therefore,  ESB must contains the certificates of both WSO2IS and Tomcat in ESB's trust store.

Default trust store of the ESB is `client-truststore.jks` keystore file which can be found at `ESB_HOME/repository/resources/security` directory.

You can export the certificate from Tomcat and WSO2IS and import them in to this keystore.  However, if you are using WSO2IS with default keystore, Then you do not want to import it to this keystore as it is already there.

You do not need to import ESB's certificate to WSO2IS or Tomcat for SSL.  It is only needed, if you are using Mutual SSL.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. May I ask you another question? If I have WS-Security enabled on my BE service (let's assume signature and encryption) and I want a XACML policy based on actions, How can I implement my WSO2 ESB Entitlement mediator to obtain the action required by the client if this is encrypted in the body? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes.. you can write some callback to entitlement mediator and get it done..  https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Entitlement+Mediator There are some default callback.  you can find some implementation from here http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator/4.2.2/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/entitlement/mediator/callback